# a4j jsFunction not triggering server side method

Tags: javascript, jsf, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I call the client side function like so  : invalidateUserSession().  I know the client function is triggered because I placed an alert in the oncomplete event. For some reason the server side method is never called though.

Client side code:

```
<a4j:jsFunction 
    name="invalidateUserSession"
    action="#{billingController.invalidateSession}"
    immediate="true"
    oncomplete="alert('invalidate');"
/>
```

---

Server side code:

```
public void invalidateSession(){
     log.info("Invalidation session...");
     FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession();
}
```

Comment: Any reason you're using `immediate` here? Have you tried without it? Also check if specifying the full `action="#{billingController.invalidateSession()}` makes a difference. And just checking the obvious, you've put a breakpoint in there and observed it never getting hit so you can assert "is never called"?

Comment: @mabi removing immediate="true" did it. Post your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments, just remove the `immediate=true` from the tag.

Obligatory link: [Debugging JSF lifecycle](http://balusc.blogspot.de/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html)

Also note that [you are still displaying the user's data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619827/how-to-invalidate-session-in-jsf-2-0) and might want to redirect/re-get the page after a session invalidation.

Answer (score 0):

Your action should return Object, for example String. See `action` attribute descption in [VDL documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_3_X/vdldoc/):

> MethodExpression representing the application action to invoke when this component is
>   activated by the user. The expression must evaluate to a public method that takes no 
>   parameters, and returns an Object (the toString() of which is called to derive the logical
>   outcome) which is passed to the NavigationHandler for this application.

Simple change void to String in method signature.

Comment: Despite the VDL saying that, it isn't [actually true](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8744193/785663). "Returning" `void` is the same as `null` here.

Comment: Thanks @mabi, I didn't know about it.