# Java Server Faces can I call a bean function without using an action to change views

Tags: jsf, action

I am new to JSF.  I can see examples of a commandLink or a button that has `action="myFunction"` and the function gets called in bean.  But I don't want to transition to another view, and if I don't provide a transition in the flow I get a No Matching Transition Exception.

```html
<jq:button action="myTestAction" buttonParam="aaa"><div onclick="javascript: setTab('teamGroups')">Team Groups in Progress</div>
</jq:button>
```

Comment: Simply make your action to return `void` or `null`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744162/difference-between-returning-null-and-from-a-jsf-action